# How can I prevent Gimp from automatically changing colors of a .png?

Tags: gimp

So I am editing a .png file from a website that I am working on. I downloaded the image (.png) and it has a yellow/green color in one of the objects. This color is important because it matches with the rest of the website's color scheme.

However, when I made my edits and saved as a new file, the green color was noticeably different.

I wondered if it was my fault on accident, so I opened the original file and saved it to a different name without editing or touching any part of the image. Yet still the color was noticeably different again.

```
    Original Color: rgb(141, 184, 73)
  Color After Save: rgb(127, 190, 65)
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening in Gimp?

Comment: Does your original PNG have any color management chunks (iCCP, gAMA, cHRM, and sRGB)?  They might be getting lost during the conversion.  If you have "pngcheck", use "pngcheck -v file.png" to find out.  If not, "pngcrush -n -v file.png" or ImageMagick's "identify -verbose file.png" are other ways of listing the PNG chunks.

Comment: I am going to try that out right now. But as I do, is there anywhere I can go to and learn more about what png chunks are?

Comment: "No errors detected in [file].png (8 chunks, 88.9% compression)." I don't see anything wrong with this file, however I remember reading somewhere that gimp optimizes images for printing when it saves which is why I was led to believe it might be gimp's fault. I could very much be wrong on that part.

Comment: You have to use the "-v" option of pngcheck to see the chunk list.  Run it against your original and your GIMP output.  Links to the PNG specification may be found at http://libpng.org/pub/png/pngdocs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with image color profiles - in GIMP, before opening your file for editing, go to `edit->preferences`, and in the `Color Management` page, set the `File Open Behavior` to `Ask What To Do` - then try different actions - one of which should preserve the numeric color values.

Comment: what do you mean by "try different actions"? What you described is a default setting in Gimp. There is no prompt upon opening a file (you are not asked what to do, the file just opens for you to edit) and there is no prompt to "preserve numeric color values"