# GIMP changes color upon export to all file types

Tags: color, gimp, export

I have an image that uses this color:

[image]

But when I export to seemingly any file type (PNG, JPG, TIFF), it changes to this color:

[image]

I have tried:

- Setting color management profile to GIMP sRGB
- Attempting what feels like every possible combination of options in the export pop-up: [image]
- Following the instructions in [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37660/how-can-i-prevent-gimp-from-automatically-changing-colors-of-a-png).

The only place where the color seems to open correctly is in the Shotwell Viewer, which I believe is one of a couple image viewers installed by default on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see the color difference between your example images so how did you create them? What are your color management options?

Comment: I have color management enabled and the profile is set to GIMP sRGB. Unless you meant something else

Comment: Is you display color-managed too?

Comment: Have you tried the `[ ] save gamma` option in the png export dialog?

Comment: @Socowi yeah I've tried that. Xenoid, not sure about my monitor, but I have discovered that depending on where I open the file (e.g., Firefox vs. Chrome, different image viewers) I get the correct or incorrect color, so my diagnosis may be incorrect

Comment: I guess the answer could be similar to the answers for "[Why does this PNG image display differently](https://superuser.com/q/579216/652023)". However, here the issue doesn't seem to be gamma support, but color profile support.